# Using SASS, How can I escape the slash character in a font declaration?

Tags: sass

I'm writing a font declaration with short-hand syntax, and I'm using SASS. I'd like to escape the '/' character to avoid SASS makes the divition operation.

```
$fontSize: 14px;
$lineHeight: 16px;
$fontName: Arial;

body
{
    font: $fontSize/$lineHeight $fontName;
}
```

This gets compiled to:

```
font: 0.875 Arial;
```

What I want to get is something like:

```
font: 14px/16px Arial;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`font: #{$fontSize}/#{$lineHeight} $fontName` should do it.

Comment: It worked!
I didn't know Interpolation would be useful this way. Tks