# What does .# mean in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I have an example code with .#

```
.#{$item} {
    background: $item;
  }
```

I can't find anything on google apart from another example

```
$fa-css-prefix: fa;
.#{$fa-css-prefix} { ... }
```

What does it mean?

Comment: When in doubt, check the output CSS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two parts in this expression,
The `.` is the css class selector, `#{}`  [**interpolation**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) syntax it allows the using of the variables in selectors and property names

```
$name: foo;
$attr: border;
p.#{$name} {
  #{$attr}-color: blue;
}
```

the generated css:

```
p.foo {
  border-color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The . Is actually for a classname and not related to the #. `#{$name}` is to output a variable name in escaped format. I case the variable had characters such as dash sass won't treat it as a subtract.

Here's an example: [Using SASS, How can I escape the slash character in a font declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015991/using-sass-how-can-i-escape-the-slash-character-in-a-font-declaration)