# SCSS considers grid-area values as mathematical operations

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to use SCSS to reduce the code I have to write, using the @each function.

My desired effect in the compiled CSS is as follows;

```css
div:nth-child(1){
 grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;
}
div:nth-child(2){
 grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}
```

So to achieve this, I wrote this small SCSS code block which uses the @each rule with a SCSS List as follows,

```
$grid-cordinates: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2, 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;

@each $current-cordinate in $grid-cordinates {
        $i : index($grid-cordinates,$current-cordinate);
        div:nth-child(#{$i}){
            grid-area: $current-cordinate;
        }
    }
```

The @each rule and indexing work as expected, but the values of the grid areas are considered as mathematical operations, (I think) and get this result.

```css
div:nth-child(1){
 grid-area: 0.25;
}
div:nth-child(2){
 grid-area: 0.08333;
}
```

In addition if the calculation of two of these grid-area values are the same, the indexing automatically selects the first value it finds in the list therefore the index would randomly have 3 in between 19 and 21 values for example. (Reason being the calculated value of 3 and 20 are the same)

This is a very small example of the actual code. (The original contains more than 20 divs).
Is there any work-around to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015991/using-sass-how-can-i-escape-the-slash-character-in-a-font-declaration also talks of SCSS doing division when coming across the slash character, and there seems to be a way round it using #

Comment: @AHaworth This did actually work, thanks for that. But this method is quite a handful since I had to interpolate each and every number in all the elements in the grid-coordinates list.  Granted, I was able to do it quickly because of multi line editing, but I was also hoping for a more long term solution.